# Query that returns a unique ID for each different clause matched?

Tags: sql-server, query-performance

I'm in a situation where I'm being submitted a (potentially quite long) list of "match entities", each of which contains user data to match, along with a unique ID for that match information.  Actual user data from matched users, along with the unique ID for that match, needs to be returned from my SQL query.  So, let's say I were given 2 entities to try and match users against, both of which were trying to match phone numbers against a user's phone number; I could match any users associated with the entities submitted along with the "match entity"'s unique ID by using a union like this (`client_handle` is the submitted unique ID):

```
SELECT
    [client_handle] = 'axtwe-wasst',
    [user_id],
    [email],
    [mobile_no],
    [firstname],
    [surname]
FROM
    [dbo].[vAPP_UsersActive]
WHERE
    [mobile_no] in ('+44 7747 122123', '+44 7904 223323')

UNION

SELECT
    [client_handle] = 'zjfft-albwq',
    [user_id],
    [email],
    [mobile_no],
    [firstname],
    [surname]
FROM
    [dbo].[vAPP_UsersActive]
WHERE
    [mobile_no] in ('+44 7758 444111', '+44 7758 444222', '+44 7758 444333')
```

The trouble with this method is that it could potentially result in a very large number of `UNION`s if large numbers of match entities are submitted to me.  1000 submitted match entities would result in 999 `UNION`s.  Is this actually an issue performance-wise, and is there a better way to achieve the result I want?  Alternatively I could just loop through each submitted match entity and run a query to match each, but then I'd have 1000 separate queries if 1000 match entities are submitted, which seems even worse.

Comment: Save your parameters into temporary table of structure `([parameters group] [client_handle], [mobile_no])` (one phone number per row, more than one row per group) and join it to data table.

Comment: Could you put that in an answer with example TSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing in the end was passing in JSON representing the different set of queries, and breaking them into a table using `OPENJSON`.  This actually makes the query simple enough that it doesn't even need to be in a stored procedure or create a temp. table, as `OPENJSON` can be used directly in a `JOIN` query, being a table-valued function:

```
SELECT
    *,
    qry.[UniqueId] AS [temp_user_match_unique_id]
FROM
    [dbo].[vAPP_UsersActive] usr
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@jsonQuery) WITH (UniqueId nvarchar(max), MobileNo nvarchar(255), Email nvarchar(255))
    ) qry ON (qry.[MobileNo] IS NOT NULL AND usr.[mobile_no] = qry.[MobileNo]) OR (qry.[Email] IS NOT NULL AND usr.[email] = qry.[Email])
```

... where the `@jsonQuery` variable is passed in with a value like:

```
[{"UniqueId":"123aaa","MobileNo":null,"Email":"joanna@t.com"},{"UniqueId":"123aaa","MobileNo":null,"Email":"james@dmn.co.uk"},{"UniqueId":"234bbb","MobileNo":"+44 7121 234588","Email":null},{"UniqueId":"234bbb","MobileNo":"+44 7121 234599","Email":null},{"UniqueId":"234bbb","MobileNo":"+44 7759 112233","Email":null}]
```

The calling code first has to flatten out the queries with the same `UniqueId` into multiple "query rows" as seen in the JSON above, and then unflattens the matches returned with a dictionary whose key is the `UniqueId`.

Answer (score 2):

Schematically:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tmp ([parameters group] INT, [client_handle] CHAR(11), [mobile_no] CHAR(15));

INSERT INTO tmp VALUES
(1,'axtwe-wasst','+44 7747 122123'),
(1,'axtwe-wasst','+44 7904 223323'),
(2,'zjfft-albwq','+44 7758 444111'),
(2,'zjfft-albwq','+44 7758 444222'),
(2,'zjfft-albwq','+44 7758 444333');

SELECT DISTINCT
    [client_handle] = tmp.[parameters group],
    [user_id],
    [email],
    [mobile_no],
    [firstname],
    [surname]
FROM
    [dbo].[vAPP_UsersActive] t
JOIN 
    tmp ON t.[mobile_no] = tmp.[mobile_no];
```

PS. `[parameters group]` is not used - on shown source data it is excess, but may be useful in real task (if so then GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT must be used).

Comment: Would this actually be better performance than a bunch of `UNION`s?  You have to create a temp table with a bunch of `INSERT`s into it... not sure that would be any better?

Comment: @Jez The best criteria is practice.. test.

Comment: @Jez Some good things to note about this solution is you're only doing one `INSERT`, just the number of values is a *large* batch for that one `INSERT`, also 1,000 values to be inserted is actually a rather *tiny* amount of data. Also the single `JOIN` clause will likely be a lot more relationally efficient than SQL Server needing to process 999 `UNION` clauses.

Comment: @Jez You can also do a `bulk insert` to the temp table, or use a Table Valued Parameter, both of which are very fast

Comment: And if you don't have Bulk Insert or TVP's available in your client driver, you can use JSON to pass a JSON doc  in a nvarchar(max) parameter and shred it with OPENJSON.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Interesting you should say that as that's exactly the solution I've decided on in the end.  I'll probably post it as the answer later.